# Can I get 4 digit integer not string in python?

Tags: python-2.7, integer, digit

[OUTPUT PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IOcV.png)

```
#### My work ####    
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

test = {
    'c': 2,
    'B': '002',
    'A': '{0:04d}'.format(2)
    }


data = {'Author': "joe", 'data': test}

a = '{0:04d}'.format(2)
b=[1, a, '{0:04d}'.format(2)]
c = {1:a}

print (a, b, '{0:04d}'.format(2))
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print('{0:04d}'.format(2))
print json.dumps(data, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))


#### Output
('0002', [1, '0002', '0002'], '0002')
0002
[1, '0002', '0002']
{1: '0002'}
0002
{
    "data": {
    "A": "0002",
    "c": 2,
    "B": "002"
},
    "Author": "joe"
}
```

I'd like to get 0002 not "0002"

It is integer number when i use '{0:04d}'.format(2) in print().

but It is printed out as string if I put it in list or dictionary.

How can I get 4 digit number as integer type in dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: 0002 and 2 are two representations of the same integer value.  If you need to distinguish between them, you should use a string.

Comment: `'{0:04d}'.format(2)` is string formatting, which returns a string.

Comment: In Python, and most other programming languages, the integer type stores the *number itself*. There, `0002` is the same as just plain `2`. It gets a bit weird over 7 because of weird parsing rules, but either way "number of digits" is not a part of the number. Asking for a four-digit integer 2 is just nonsensical.

Comment: Oh, this has something to do with JSON serialization. That could be relevant if you have a misbehaving API. What are you trying to do with the JSON?

Comment: I'd like to store information (dictionary type) in JSON file.
It sort of my homework. there is condition. 
Padding number should be numbers with 4 digit, not a string.
so I found '{}'.format(integer) but i didn't work in list or dictionary

Comment: What do you mean by "padding numbers"?

Comment: But it was integer when I used  "print('{0:04d}'.format(2))"

Comment: the code i posted is sample.
actually I want to get images information. like name, size..
for example,  image's name are "a_0001_0002","a_0001_0003","a_0001_0004".... then  padding number is 0002,0003,0004.....

Comment: @AJGO That was specifically with output. You can print anything you want, but that doesn't mean it is stored *by Python* that way. And what you've said of your assignment makes no sense; [JSON does not allow leading zeroes](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-6 "Official definition of JSON, section on numbers"). Would it be allowed to use numbers that are actually between 1000 and 9999 for these positions?

Comment: Oh. I see....
the number start 0 not 1000.
I learned it from you Daniel H.
Thanks a lot!!!